# Can't get htaccess rule to work: force SSL on all pages, force non-SSL on two specific pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am no htaccess expert, but after Googling for two hours I gave up. Maybe you can help me?

I have my entire site on SSL. However, I have two pages that reference non-secure dynamic content from elsewhere. I need these to be on `http` instead of `https`.

The first part of my rules work. All the site is forced to SSL except for those two pages. However, the last part doesn't: force those two pages to non-SSL. It is probably very stupid but does anyone see where I go wrong?

```
#add www. if missing  WORKS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#force SSL/https WORKS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webshop2/localize\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webshop2/layoutstripper\.php
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#force http DOES NOT WORK
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webshop2/localize\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webshop2/layoutstripper\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `[OR]` flag in your second SSL rule. The 2 conditions you have essentially say:

- the request **must** be HTTPS
- the URI **must start with**: `/webshop2/localize.php`
- the URI **must start with**: `/webshop2/layoutstripper.php`

As you can see, the last 2 conditions will always fail, as the request can't be BOTH at the same time. If you add an `[OR]` flag in there, it makes it true if the URI is one or the other:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webshop2/localize\.php [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webshop2/layoutstripper\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am SO STUPID!
30 years of programming and I cannot negate an AND.
THANK YOU!!!!